# TDD how to handle a change in a mocked object

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

In writing unit tests, for each object that the unit interacts with, I am taking these steps (stolen from my understanding of JBrains' [Integration Tests are a Scam](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/integration-tests-scam)):

1. Write a test in the unit to ensure it is sending the correct call and params to the collaborating object
2. Write a test in the unit that ensures it handles all possible responses from the collaborating object. These responses are all mocked so the unit is tested in isolation.
3. Write a test in the collaborating object to make sure it accepts the call and params.
4. Write tests to make sure each possible response is sent back.

My question comes around when I decide to refactor an object that has responses mocked in step 2.  If I change the way the object responds to a call, none of the tests that other objects have for that call will fail because they have all been mocked to match the old style. How do you keep mocks up to date with the objects they are mocking?  Is there a best practice for this?  Or have I completely misunderstood things and am doing it all wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do it this way.

Suppose I have to change the responses from interface method `foo()`. I gather all the collaboration tests that stub `foo()` in a list. I gather all the contract tests for method `foo()`, or if I don't have contract tests, I gather all the tests for all the current implementations of `foo()` in a list.

Now I create a version control branch, because it'll be messy for a while.

I `@Ignore` (JUnit speak) or otherwise disable the collaboration tests that stub `foo()` and start re-implementing and re-running them one by one. I get them all passing. I can do this without touching any production implementation of `foo()`.

Now I re-implement the objects that implement `foo()` one by one with expected results that match the new return values from the stubs. Remember: stubs in collaboration tests correspond to expected results in contract tests.

At this point, all the collaboration tests now assume the new responses from `foo()` and the contract tests/implementation tests now expect the new responses from `foo()`, so It Should All Just Work.(TM)

Now integrate your branch and pour yourself some wine.

Answer (score 2):

Revised:
This is a tradeoff. Ease of testing by isolating an object from its environment vs Confidence that it all works when all the pieces come together.

1. Aim for stable roles: Think in terms of client-oriented roles (rather than a bunch of methods). I've found roles (written in terms of client's needs / client-first / outside-in) are less volatile. Check if the role is a leaky abstraction betraying implementation details. Also watch for roles that are change-magnets (and come up with a mitigation plan).
2. If you *have* to make changes, see if you can *'lean on the compiler'*. Things like changing a method signature will be flagged up nicely by the compiler. So use it.
3. If the compiler cannot help you in spotting the changes, *be more diligent that usual* to see if you haven't missed a spot (client usage).
4. Finally you fall back on acceptance tests to catch such issues - ensure that Object A and Collaborators B,C,D are playing by the same assumptions (protocol). If something manages to escape your dragnet, chances are high that at least one test should spot it.

Comment: Falling back on acceptance tests should help, but not be necessary. I'd rather not try to rely on them, but I'm happy to have them as an emergency mistake detection system.

Comment: @J.B.Rainsberger - Yes. I was not implying that every interaction needs to be a high-level/system test. However some system test should be able to spot any anomalous change in the interaction. We've sparred before on this http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/testdrivendevelopment/message/32743 Not sure how I missed the last message on that thread. I would consider Exceptions thrown as part of the contract (you seem to imply that they are implementation details).. Could you elaborate on that? Apart from that, changes can be made safely, given an adequate amount of diligence to not miss any spots

Comment: First, exceptions thrown certainly represent part of the contract, but I don't like to add exceptions to a contract unless it's essential. Next, at most importantly, I don't like that your answer cites acceptance tests as the first and most significant way to solve this problem, since I generally treat them as the last and weakest line of defence. Diligence, we agree, gives us the best chance of success.

Comment: @J.B.Rainsberger - yeah.. I can see how a reader can get that idea... Revised

Answer (score 0):

First, it's definitely harder to get this level of coverage with integration tests, so I think unit tests are still superior. However, I think you have a point. It's hard to keep your objects' behavior in sync.

An answer to this is to have partial integration tests that have real services 1 level deep, but beyond that are mocks. For instance:

```
var sut = new SubjectUnderTest(new Service1(Mock.Of<Service1A>(), ...), ...);
```

This solves the problem of keeping behaviors in sync, but compounds the level of complexity because you now have to setup many more mocks.

You can solve this problem in a functional programming language using discriminated unions. For instance:

```
// discriminated union
type ResponseType
| Success
| Fail of string   // takes an argument of type string

// a function
let saveObject x =
    if x = "" then
        Fail "argument was empty"
    else
        // do something
        Success

let result = saveObject arg 

// handle response types
match result with
| Success -> printf "success"
| Fail msg -> printf "Failure: %s" msg
```

You define a discriminated union called `ResponseType` that has a number of possible states, some of which can take arguments and other metadata. Every time you access a return value you have to deal with possible various conditions. If you were to add another failure type or success type, the compiler would give you warnings for each time you don't handle the new member.

This concept can go a long way toward handling the evolution of a program. C#, Java, Ruby and other languages use exceptions to communicate failure conditions. But these failure conditions are frequently not "exceptional" circumstances at all, which ends up leading to the situation you are dealing with.

I think functional languages are the closest to providing the best answer to your question. Frankly, I don't think there is a perfect answer, or even a good answer in many languages. But compile-time checking can go a long way

Comment: I disagree that keeping mocks and implementations in sync is hard. It can be tedious, but it's not really hard, in general. I treat this the way I treated TDD 12 years ago: a newly-discovered part of my job that people had never explained to me before.

Comment: @J.B.Rainsberger keeping mocks and implementations is really hard, if you are working with deadlines or developers who does not like unit tests.

Comment: @KeremBaydoğan I work with deadlines. Understanding the code that I write helps me meet deadlines. Allowing that code to worsen over time threatens my ability to meet deadlines.

Comment: @KeremBaydoğan If you work with programmers who do not like unit tests, then every automated testing technique you use will eventually fail. If you want to use automated tests to help you in your work, then you will find it difficult to share code with people who do not want to work that way.

Comment: @J.B.Rainsberger I am feeling the same as you about understanding the code that I'm working on. What I am trying to say we should not trust developers about keeping mock and real software components in synch. Every developer should write one mock object for every real object that they are maintaining and when they finish doing that they should write a unit test and compare every behaviour of the real object with the mock one. Because comment section is not large enough, I have posted an answer. It would be great if you take a look at it and tell if something is not right.

Comment: @KeremBaydoğan We should be able to trust them. If we can't trust them, then we are not working together, and the rules certainly change. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should not trust human beings (even yourself) about keeping mock and real software components in synch.

I hear you ask?

> Then what is your proposal?

**My proposal is;**

1. You should write mocks.
2. You should **only** write mocks for software components that you **maintain**.
3. If you maintain a software component with another developer, you and the other developer should maintain mock of that component **together**.
4. **You should not mock someone else's component**.
5. When you write a unit test for your component, **you should write a separate unit test** for the mock of that component. Let's call that **`MockSynchTest`**.
6. In **`MockSynchTest`** you should compare every behavior of the mock with the real component.
7. When you make changes to your component, you should run the **`MockSynchTest`** to see if you made your mock and component out-of-synch or not.
8. If you need the mock of a component that you do not maintain while testing your components, ask the developer of that component about the mock. If she can provide you with a well tested mock, good for her and lucky for you. If she can not, kindly ask her to follow this guideline and provide you a well tested mock.

This way if you accidentally make your mock out of synch, there will be a failing test case there to warn you.

This way you do not need to know the implementation details of the foreign component for mocking.

[How-to-write-good-tests#dont-mock-type-you-dont-own](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/How-to-write-good-tests#dont-mock-type-you-dont-own)

Comment: In a very low-trust environment, these rules might help, but I do not recommend these as general rules. I interpret these rules as a way to cope with working in an environment where we share code with people, but we do not work as a team. These rules seem to me to simply treat co-workers as if they were producing a product that we consume; and in the case, we should not live in the same code base.